# Showing a div only once per time when user on the site doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, session-storage

I want to ask about javascript, how to show a div once in one visit?

I have the code that I have work below. But still not working.

**JS Show Div Once Per Time**

```
(function() {
    var visited = sessionStorage.getItem('visited');
    if (!visited) {
        document.getElementById("popupMode").style.visibility = "visible";
        sessionStorage.setItem('visited', true);
    }
})();
```

**What I want:**

I have a popup div to give the user the option to choose the mode. When user have selected the popup will disappear. When I refresh the page I want the popup not appear again, it appears only once at the beginning of our visit to the web.

If you don't mind, I also have a switcher mode in the popup but it won't switch.

for the full code, you can see in [My Codepen](https://codepen.io/fikryrmdhna/pen/QWNqYLa)

**POPUP MODE**

```
<!-- Popup Mode -->
<div id="popupMode">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0 h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-12 main-content">
        <div id="modeChoice">
          <div class="title">
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
            <p>
              You can switch the button from light mode<br>to dark mode
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="choose-mode">
            <div id="modeSwitcher">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
              <label class="label" for="chk">
                 <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
                 <div class="ball"></div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="buttonPopupMode">
            <a href="#" class="btn button-primary">UNDERSTAND</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**FULL JS**

```
window.onload = function() {

  (function() {
    var visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
    if (!visited) {
      document.getElementById("popupMode").style.visibility = "visible";
      localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
    }
  })();

  if (localStorage.darkMode == "true") {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
    document.getElementById("chk").checked = true;
  } else {
    document.body.classList.toggle('light');
  }
};

document.getElementById("chk").addEventListener('change', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
  document.body.classList.toggle('light');
  localStorage.darkMode = (localStorage.darkMode == "true") ? "false" : "true";
});

$("#popupMode").delay(3000).fadeIn(500);

$("#buttonPopupMode .button-primary").on('click', function() {
  $('#popupMode').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line `$("#popupMode").delay(3000).fadeIn(500);` inside `if (!visited) {...}`.

Updated code will be like below.

```
window.onload = function() {

  (function() {
    var visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
    if (!visited) {
      document.getElementById("popupMode").style.visibility = "visible";
      localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
      // Add below line. 
      $("#popupMode").delay(3000).fadeIn(500);
    }
  })();

  if (localStorage.darkMode == "true") {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
    document.getElementById("chk").checked = true;
  } else {
    document.body.classList.toggle('light');
  }
};

document.getElementById("chk").addEventListener('change', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
  document.body.classList.toggle('light');
  localStorage.darkMode = (localStorage.darkMode == "true") ? "false" : "true";
});

// remove below line.
// $("#popupMode").delay(3000).fadeIn(500);

$("#buttonPopupMode .button-primary").on('click', function() {
  $('#popupMode').hide();
})
```

---

**P.S.**
**localStorage vs sessionStorage**
`localStorage` and `sessionStorage` accomplish the exact same thing and have the same API, but with `sessionStorage - the data is persisted only until the window or tab is closed`, while with `localStorage - the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data`. I would suggest to use `localStorage` but its up to you and your requirement you can choose preferable.

Comment: oh bro, I've edited the code with the one you have. but the div does not appear @Karan

Comment: i change localStorage with sessionStorage and it works

Comment: If you have tried hard refreshing the page then also it would have work. The reason it wasn't showing div could be that you might already having `visited` value in `localStorage`.

Comment: however, using sessionStorage works fine. Is it okay in the future if I use it (sessionStorage)?

Comment: I have updated answer and explained difference between `localStorage` & `sessionStorage`.

Comment: thanks for explaining it, it really helped me @Karan